# check if sorl-thumbnail has already cached an image

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm running a django app with sorl-thumbnail and a lot of remote images (sorl loads image from external source).

Ideally I'd like to check if sorl has already cached an image in my template, and if not, load the image with ajax.

Reading the doc I found a `exist` method which seems to always return `true`

```
{% thumbnail item.image "160x200" crop="center" as im %}
    {% if im.exists %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
    {% else %}
        <!-- load image with ajax -->
    {% endif %}
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Is there a method I can use to check if a image has already been cached in a template?

Comment: {% thumbnail item.image "160x200" crop="center" as im %} creates the thumbnail if it does not exist. Calling exists() on the next line will always return True since it has recently been created if it did not exist.

Comment: this makes sense. Is there a way to create a thumbnail object without creating the actual image?

I could query the kv store in my view. But this seems a little bit hacky.

Comment: It could be done by using some of the code in get_thumbnail in sorl.thumbnail.base. I think that if you used line 32 to 50 and made function out of it returning True/False based on the cached variable.

Comment: In case you prefer python code instead raw SQL, you can read [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723599/check-if-sorl-thumbnail-has-already-cached-an-image-using-the-low-level-api/20733406#20733406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a method for my model.

This is some dirty raw sql using expensive %LIKE%.

```
def has_image_cached(self):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM thumbnail_kvstore WHERE value LIKE %s",['%'+self.imageurl+'%'])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            return False
        return True
```