# Check if sorl thumbnail has already cached an image using the low level API

Tags: python, django, caching, sorl-thumbnail

Sorl thumbnail has a low-level API that allows you to do, for example:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
im = get_thumbnail(my_file, '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
```

This returns a reference to the cached file.  If it's already been created, it's super quick.  However, if it has to create it for the first time it can take a long time when using remote storage such as S3.

Is there a way to run a command in Python (ie. not in a template) to check if sorl will have to generate a thumbnail for the first time?

PS. I'm aware of similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636647/check-if-sorl-thumbnail-has-already-cached-an-image) but this is asking about it in a template context, and has a hacky solution as an answer that uses custom SQL and not the sorl API.

Answer (score 1):

In my version `sorl.thumbnail`, `11.12`, the method `get_thumbnail` is defined in sorl.thumbnail.base.py and starts as follows:

```
def get_thumbnail(self, file_, geometry_string, **options):
    """..."""
    source = ImageFile(file_)
    for key, value in self.default_options.iteritems():
        options.setdefault(key, value)
    # ...
    for key, attr in self.extra_options:
        value = getattr(settings, attr)
        if value != getattr(default_settings, attr):
            options.setdefault(key, value)
    name = self._get_thumbnail_filename(source, geometry_string, options)
    thumbnail = ImageFile(name, default.storage)
    cached = default.kvstore.get(thumbnail)
    if cached:
        return cached
    if not thumbnail.exists():
        ...
```

If you use this code and return something like

```
cached or thumbnail.exists()
```

this should give you the desired result.